# ReferenceError: event is not defined firefox d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, error-handling

I get this error in firefox only on this line:

```
.on("mousemove", function() {
    return tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY - 10) + "px").style("left", (event.pageX + 10) + "px");
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `d3.event`. `d3.event` stores the current event, if any.

```
.on("mousemove", function() {
    return tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 10) + "px").style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 10) + "px");
});
```

> Note that the first parameter of the mouse over function is the data
>   bonded to the corresponding element and second parameter is it's
>   index.